# CloudFlare SSL + Heroku custom domain not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns, cloudflare

It's been more than 48 hours after I update my CloudFlare DNS setting to point to my Heroku app. The custom domain works fine now without https://.

But when I try the https:// version, I get this:

[image]

This is my Heroku custom domain setting:

[image]

This is my CloudFlare DNS setting:

[image]

This is my CloudFlare SSL setting:

[image]

And lastly, this is my CloudFlare page rules setting:

[image]

I follow this [CloudFlare guide](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205893698-Configure-CloudFlare-and-Heroku-over-HTTPS) and not skip any step of it.

What am I missing here?

My app (http): `http://beta.futurelab.my/`

My app (https): `https://beta.futurelab.my/`

My Heroku app: `http://future-lab-production.herokuapp.com` OR `https://future-lab-production.herokuapp.com`

I want my app only available at `https://beta.futurelab.my/` and force SSL sitewide.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you added the CNAME record to Cloudflare but not enabled it. You need to click on the cloud icon placed on the right of your Cloudflare DNS record row. It should turn to orange when it is enabled.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation as @ZulhilmiZainudin, but the cloud icon is orange and I'm still getting that error. My SSL certificate is also active. Is it just a matter of waiting 48 hours?

Comment: Once you pointed your domain's NS records correctly to Cloudflare, it should not take that long but pointing NS record may take up to 48 hours. You can check your domain's DNS record with a tool like http://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx also it is better to flush your DNS cache in your computer.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. The orange icon is for enabling HTTP proxying through Clouflare. DNS should work even with icon greyed.

Comment: @Overdrivr Actually DNS is working when even the icon is gray but the problem here is that when HTTP is not proxied through Cloudflare, the SSL feature doesn't work which makes https site inaccessible.

Comment: Ah yes but in that case heroku also provides automated SSL certificates, so you can use that to get ssl working too

Comment: @Overdrivr I think by the time this question was asked, Heroku SSL was not announced and also it's available for paid subscriptions.  But yes, I agree, Heroku SSL is a better option if the case is only about the SSL certificate.